# Reverse substring to get a palindrome

Tags: string, algorithm, substring, palindrome

Given a string consisting of lower-case characters from English alphabets, we want to reverse a substring from the string such that the string becomes a palindrome.

**Note :** A Palindrome is a string which equals its reverse.

We need to tell if some substring exists which could be reversed to convert the string into palindrome.

**Example :** Let string be "zakdakdz". Then the answer for this string is yes, since we can reverse the string between indexes 4 and 6 to get zakddkaz

**Basic Approach :** Try to reverse each and every substring and check if we get palindrome or not. However, this is bad approach for a long string.

So is there a better way to solve it ?

Can there be faster than O(N^2) approach ?

Comment: Yes, of course there is. They're probably thinking of walking through the string from both the beginning and the end, and comparing characters.

Comment: @JerryCoffin And what is it ?

Comment: @JerryCoffin What you mean by "They're thinking" ?

Comment: I mean "whomever assigned this homework probably wants you to complete the assignment this way."

Comment: @JerryCoffin Hey why think its a home work ?

Comment: Hey "topcoder" (really?) who checks for palindromes in real life if it isn't homework?

Comment: If "homework" includes competitive programming endeavors, probably no one.

Comment: @MarkRansom In Interviews ?

Comment: This is not really off-topic here, but I think that if you are really clueless you may be best off by posting a challenge on Programming puzzles & code golf ;)

Comment: Its a problem from a live contest at Codechef.com (http://www.codechef.com/TCFS15P/problems/PALINREV).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quadratic-time algorithm, down from cubic (I strongly suspect that a further improvement, to linear-time or perhaps n log n, is possible). Suppose that the string looks like this:

```
X...X .
```

I claim that, if there exists a substring whose reversal makes this string a palindrome, then there exists such a substring not including either `X`. The case argument to this effect is that, if it includes both `X`s, then the string already is a palindrome. If it includes just one `X`, say the first one by symmetry, then the substring must look like

```
X...X...X ,
^^^^^
```

because the second `X` is unmoved. We can shrink the reversed substring to

```
X...X...X .
 ^^^
```

The quadratic-time algorithm is to scan in from the ends until we find a mismatch. Then try all substrings beginning at the left mismatched letter and all substrings ending at the right mismatched letter.

Comment: Can you provide some pseudocode or so ?It will make things more clear

Answer (score 0):

Strings with length below 2 are palindromes, and stay so reversing each and every substring. If I was less lazy, I'd probably
scan longer strings from both ends inwards for a difference in character (or meeting in the middle), then from the middle outwards. Knowing the non-palindromic regions, a reversal of one would turn the whole string into a palindrome iff they were identical.

Comment: can you please provide some pseudocode?Also remember we can only reverse a single string

Comment: @cook topcoder: I was about to reply harshly. `remember` and `we` ring even more "assignment bells": describe the application, if it is neither an assignment nor a competition, or state upfront what it is, inviting help in favour of solutions. "zakdakdz": from outside in, you find 'a' (1 from the left end) and 'd' (6 from the left (1 from right)) differ, inside out, 'd'(3) and 'a'(4). If the substrings from 1-3 and 4-6 (inclusive) differed, no single reversal would produce a palindrome, as they are equal, pick one to reverse.

Comment: I think you didnt get question